# Managing Android shared resources in repository

Tags: android

I have multiple Android projects that I need to manage in various Git repositories, all of which are being managed by repo.  I have found a `.gitignore` file for Android managed by Git, but I don't see things like image files being ignored:
   https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore

I have also read that creating an Android library which contains my resources would allow for a module that is not an `.apk`, rather a resource for apps to use. 
   https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Is there a best practice for storing shared resources?

Comment: Please note that ["best practices" questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265928/2747593). This question *might* be on-topic for [Programmers.se], so consider posting there instead. Please note that [cross posting is generally frowned upon](//meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info), so you should either (1) post a new question there and delete this one, or (2) flag your question for a [moderator to migrate](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/269535).

Answer (score 0):

Creating an Android library project is trivial; distributing it to your other downstream apps is really the interesting part.

Ideally, it would be nice to do this in a way that mimcs how you use other dependencies on Android, namely adding an artifact to the `dependencies` block in your `build.gradle` file and having Gradle automatically fetch it. The trouble there is it's a private library that you wouldn't want to host on JCenter, Maven Central, or other public artifact hosting. Some companies have their own internal instances of artifact hosting servers specifically for this.

Fortunately, you can use the [`maven-publish` Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) to use Maven locally (on your machine) and achieve the same effect. First, in the library project's `build.gradle` file, you need

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'your.package.namespace'
            artifactId 'library.name'
            version '0.1' // for example
            artifacts = configurations.archives.artifacts
            artifact sourceJar
        }
    }
}
```

Next, you need to publish this library to your local Maven cache by running

```
./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
```

Next in your downstream project, add `mavenLocal` as a repository and add your dependency using the group id, artifact id, and version you used earlier:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    /* more repositories here */
}

dependencies {
    compile 'your.package.namespace:library.name:version'
    /* more dependencies here */
}
```

This should achieve what you want.

The downside is every developer will have to pull down the library project at least once and run the command to publish to their Maven local, and if the library project changes at all, the version must be updated, and all devs need to pull down the changes and publish again locally. This can get a little unwieldy.

Many companies run their own artifact hosting server instances internally to avoid this, so you publish once to the internal hosting and downstream projects just update the version in their `build.gradle` and let it sync automatically. This requires some additional configuration for the `publishing` block (of the library) and the `repositories` block (of the downstream projects); I leave it to you to research that if you intend to go that direction.